# C# mysql parameters value is null?

Tags: c#, mysql

So I'm trying to pass in parameters for point strings, all my columns are marked not null in my DB however when i try to run the below code it tells me column Lat cannot be null.  Is there something i'm overlooking?

```
string latParameter = "'Point(" + latString + ")'";
            string lonParameter = "'Point(" + lonString + ")'";

            string mySQLfinishedProcessing = " insert into zipcodes " +
              "set zipcode = '" + zipcodeString + "'" +
              ",State = '" + StateString + "'" +
              ",City = '" + CityString + "'" +
              ",lat = GeomFromText(@latParam)"+
              ",lon = GeomFromText(@lonParam)"+
            ",StateCode = '" + StateCodeString2 + "'";

            //File.AppendAllText(@"C:\sqlupdater.txt", mySQLfinishedProcessing + ";\n");

            MySqlConnection configCON = new MySqlConnection(SQLStringClass.zipCONString);
            MySqlCommand CounterLogs = new MySqlCommand(mySQLfinishedProcessing, configCON);
            CounterLogs.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@latParam", latParameter));
            CounterLogs.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@lonParam", lonParameter));
            configCON.Open();
            CounterLogs.ExecuteNonQuery();
            configCON.Close();
```

yes, latString and lonString has values.

string latParameter = 'Point(40.92233)'
string lonParameter = 'Point(-72.63708)'

okay it appears the be cause there is only a single reference to a point, i change string latParameter = 'Point(40.92233 12)' it takes just fine.  But do I really want to put both my lat/lon in 1 point column?

ugh nevermind that works fine in MySQl Edit, but in C# it still doesnt resolve the issue.  The problem is the string lonParameter needs to contain a ;

here is the correct code.

```
 string latParameter = "Point(" + latString + " " +lonString+");";

            string mySQLfinishedProcessing = " insert into zipcodes " +
              "set zipcode = '" + zipcodeString + "'" +
              ",State = '" + StateString + "'" +
              ",City = '" + CityString + "'" +
              ",Location = GeomFromText(@latParam)"+
            ",StateCode = '" + StateCodeString2 + "'";

            //File.AppendAllText(@"C:\sqlupdater.txt", mySQLfinishedProcessing + ";\n");

            MySqlConnection configCON = new MySqlConnection(SQLStringClass.zipCONString);
            MySqlCommand CounterLogs = new MySqlCommand(mySQLfinishedProcessing, configCON);
            CounterLogs.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@latParam", latParameter));
            configCON.Open();
            CounterLogs.ExecuteNonQuery();
            configCON.Close();
```

Comment: Well, what is the value of `latString` etc? Also, why aren't the other strings parameters? Come to mention it, why can't the call to `Point()` use parameters?

Comment: why do i need to make them all parameters?  the other values are just int's and varchar?

Comment: @mike in your smysqlfinishedprocessingstring your lat = is lowercase maybe u need to do Lat =  instead cause columns are case sensitive in SQL

Comment: @Mike actually I was thinking of SQL injection. concatenating values is very very dangerous.

Comment: No it's not a case sensitive issue

Comment: I must move to `smallville '; drop table Customers--`

Comment: added an update figured it out

Comment: Re your edit - without both, it *isn't a point* - it is just a number. You need two values to identify a position on a 2D surface

Answer (score 1):

you are writing insert statment with wrong syntax. it must be

```
string mySQLfinishedProcessing = " insert into zipcodes(zipcode ,State ,City ,lat ,lon ,StateCode ) values ( " +
          "'" + zipcodeString + "'" +
          ",'" + StateString + "'" +
          ",'" + CityString + "'" +
          ",GeomFromText(@latParam)" +
          ",GeomFromText(@lonParam)" +
        ",'" + StateCodeString2 + "')";
```

Comment: No that formatting is fine, i make these values allow null and everything inserts right, i do my inserts like this allt he time

Answer (score 0):

If GeomFromText is a db function, it's probably returning null for whatever you're passing in.